# SaveChanges returns 0 and not saving data at all

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I got a strange issue with the `SaveChanges()` method of Entity Framework. The issue is that it returns 0 and is not updating the table data at all. What could the issue be? Any ideas? I have to update a existing users data

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "User")]
public ActionResult Settings(User _users)
{
    using (MydbEntities db = new MydbEntities())
    {
        var u = new User();
        string _Email = User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString();

        if(db.Users.Any(x=>x.Email == _Email))
        {
            u.BusinessName = _users.BusinessName;
            u.Address = _users.Address;
            u.VatNumber = _users.VatNumber;
            u.PhoneNumber = _users.PhoneNumber;
            u.IsBusinessUser = _users.IsBusinessUser;

            var foo = db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're *trying to do* is **load** an existing user, and if it exists, then update it.

Try this code:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "User")]
public ActionResult Settings(User _users)
{
    using (MydbEntities db = new MydbEntities())
    {
        string _Email = User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString();

        // try to find the existing user in the database
        User existing = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == _Email);

        if(existing != null)
        {
            // if you *DID* find a user - then update its properties
            existing.BusinessName = _users.BusinessName;
            existing.Address = _users.Address;
            existing.VatNumber = _users.VatNumber;
            existing.PhoneNumber = _users.PhoneNumber;
            existing.IsBusinessUser = _users.IsBusinessUser;

            var foo = db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

First, you **load** the existing user, and if you've found one, you update its properties, and now the `SaveChanges()` call *should* update that existing user for you